# Table/Tabular Row Spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, pdftex, rowcolor

I'm trying to tex a table with alternating rows. It's working but there is something like a non-colored gap/spacing between the rows, so it looks very weird:

### [image]

Here is the code for the example above:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{My Title}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
  \centering\vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}\toprule
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Name} \\\midrule
    Animal & Monkey \\\midrule
    Animal & Lion \\\midrule
    Fruit & Apple \\
    Fruit & Banana \\\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Have anyone an idea how to solve this without many changes referring the packages/markup? Are there some parameter to adjust?

Thanks a lot & best regards,

Felix

Comment: Providing both horizontal rules *and* alternating row colors is quite redundant and doesn't contribute to the table's readability. If you want to keep the alternating row colors, consider dispensing with all interior `\midrule` statements.

Comment: The main feature of the `booktabs` package is to add vertical space around horizontal rules. A you see here....

Comment: The reason for using both horizontal rules and alternating row colors is, that I wanna improve the readability (row colors) and grouping some of these rows (lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\hline` instead of `\midrule`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{My Title}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
  \centering\vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}\hline
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Name} \\
    \hline
    Animal & Monkey \\
    \hline
    Animal & Lion \\
    \hline
    Fruit & Apple \\
    \hline
    Fruit & Banana \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for!

Do you know a possibility to combine `\hline` with higher rows? O:-)

Comment: An hackish solution should be : `\vspace{1mm}Type\vspace{1mm}` for each cell.

Comment: Have `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` any negative side effects?

Comment: @fheck I don't think

Answer (score 4):

It is due to the fact the `booktabs` introduces the `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` before and after a rule (`\toprule`, `\bottomrule` and `\midrule` etc). The `\rowcolors` is not painting this space with the colors so we get the gap. This can be prevented by drawing a `\hrule` of height `\aboverulesep` above  and `\belowrulesep` below with the same color as that of the row.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\belowrulesepcolor}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \vspace{-\belowrulesep}
    \bgroup
      \color{#1}%
      \hrule height\belowrulesep
    \egroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\aboverulesepcolor}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \bgroup
      \color{#1}%
      \hrule height\aboverulesep
    \egroup
    \vspace{-\aboverulesep}
  }%
}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{My Title}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
  \centering\vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}\toprule
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Name} \\\midrule
    Animal & Monkey \\\midrule
    \belowrulesepcolor{gray!20}
    Animal & Lion \\
    \aboverulesepcolor{gray!20}\midrule
    Fruit & Apple \\
%    \belowrulesepcolor{gray!20}   %% not needed since there is no midrule.
    Fruit & Banana \\\aboverulesepcolor{gray!20}
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But better way is to ditch those `\midrule`s since the rows are highlighted with colours

Comment: thanks for your effort! Think I'll use the standard `\hline` instead und try additionally to increase the row height.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code of the solution I've finally chosen:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{My Title}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
  \centering\vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}\toprule
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Name} \\\midrule
    Animal & Monkey \\\midrule
    Animal & Lion \\\midrule
    Fruit & Apple \\
    Fruit & Banana \\\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```